# Python, solve non-linear equation for a variable

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

Using Python and SymPy I am trying to solve this equation for b:

[image: Text]

My code:

```
From sympy import * 
b = Symbol('b') 
x = ((b/(2*math.pi*math.e))*((math.pi*b)**(1/b)))**(1/(2*(b-1)))
solve(x-1.0034,b)
```

And I get this error: *NotImplementedError: multiple generators...No algorithms are implemented to solve equation...*

Do you know where is the mistake? Or is it possible that the equaiton is so difficult that Python can not solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `pi` and `E` from sympy:

```
In [21]: b = Symbol('b')                                                                                                          

In [22]: eq = ((b/(2*math.pi*math.e))*((math.pi*b)**(1/b)))**(1/(2*(b-1))) - 1.0034                                               

In [23]: eq                                                                                                                       
Out[23]: 
                                                1            
                                             ───────         
                                             2⋅b - 2         
⎛                     b ____________________⎞                
⎝0.0585498315243192⋅b⋅╲╱ 3.14159265358979⋅b ⎠        - 1.0034

In [24]: eq = ((b/(2*pi*E))*((pi*b)**(1/b)))**(1/(2*(b-1))) - 1.0034                                                              

In [25]: eq                                                                                                                       
Out[25]: 
                  1            
               ───────         
               2⋅b - 2         
⎛  b _____  -1⎞                
⎜b⋅╲╱ π⋅b ⋅ℯ  ⎟                
⎜─────────────⎟        - 1.0034
⎝     2⋅π     ⎠
```

The equation is transcendental and it is unlikely that analytic solutions exist. Potentially there is a Lambert form for this but `solve` does not find anything.

You can solve it numerically though using `nsolve`:

```
In [29]: sol = nsolve(eq, b, 2)                                                                                                   

In [30]: sol                                                                                                                      
Out[30]: 14.3368885826882

In [31]: eq.n(subs={b:sol})                                                                                                       
Out[31]: 7.22915270916583e-19
```